# need to launch an ec2 in an existing subnet using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have created a VPC and a public subnet and i have saved the subnet id into file called "SubnetId.txt". the code is below:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/16')
vpc.create_tags(Tags=[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"Test_VPC"}])
vpc.wait_until_available()
ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2Client.modify_vpc_attribute( VpcId = vpc.id , EnableDnsSupport = { 'Value': True } )
ec2Client.modify_vpc_attribute( VpcId = vpc.id , EnableDnsHostnames = { 'Value': True } )
publicsubnet = ec2.create_subnet(CidrBlock='10.0.1.0/24', VpcId=vpc.id)
IGW = ec2.create_internet_gateway()
vpc.attach_internet_gateway(InternetGatewayId=IGW.id)
routetable = vpc.create_route_table()
route = routetable.create_route(DestinationCidrBlock='0.0.0.0/0', GatewayId=IGW.id)
routetable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=publicsubnet.id)
sg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='SSH, HTTP & HTTPS', Description='Allowed SSH, HTTP & HTTPS', VpcId=vpc.id)
sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0', IpProtocol='tcp', FromPort=22, ToPort=22)
sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0', IpProtocol='tcp', FromPort=80, ToPort=80)
sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0', IpProtocol='tcp', FromPort=443, ToPort=443)
f = open("SubnetId.txt", "w")
f.write(publicsubnet.id)
f.close()
```

Now I will run this code and VPC and Subnet will be created.

I have written a code to launch an instance in the existing subnet. The subnet id will be pulled from the is text file called "SubnetID.txt". But the code is not working.

```
def file_read(fname):
    with open (fname, "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.readlines()
file_read('SubnetId.txt')
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
VM = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-0ce933e2ae91880d3',
 InstanceType='t2.micro',
 MaxCount=1,
 MinCount=1,
 NetworkInterfaces=[{
 'SubnetId': data,
 'DeviceIndex': 0,
 'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
 }],
 KeyName='ec2-keypair')
```

```
The error it shows is: 'SubnetId': data,
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

I just want to launch an instance in the existing subnet and existing security group

Comment: Actually, `data` variable is not available outside of function file_read's scope.

Comment: So, how to rectify it..

Comment: All of I can think of is.......Either you can perform your action in same scope or declare a variable outside of func's scope and update it's value inside func... https://repl.it/repls/SizzlingImperturbableCircles